# in the sentence "will have to be sold" I wonder why sold is named in this form?

Tags: grammar

I apologize if the question is stupid ,but I can't remember/understand why *sell* is in this form, and not *sell* for example.Can *be sold* by this steady phrase? Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking about active vs passive voice?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the sentence from the textbook, sounds like this: " *i regret that the company will have to be sold*."

Comment: Yes and what is your question about that sentence?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I can't understand why / by what rule we write be sold, and not be sell

Comment: Because that is how you form the passive in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Sold” is a past tense word, but what we’re essentially saying is that it will need to **become** sold, i.e. it “will have to” (at some point in the future) “be sold”.

Comment: thank you, and there is a name for the rule to google or just logically so ?

Comment: I don’t know of a name for the rule, but simply googling the definition should explain it. It’s a common usage for verbs, e.g., “must be removed/explained/locked/cooked/ad infinitum”.

Comment: thank you for your help :)